# Баг с модальным окном bootstrap - прокрутка страницы

Tags: bootstrap

При открытии модального окна страница прокручивается вверх. При закрытии - возвращается в то место, где находится ссылка, открывающая окно.

Версия 3.3.7

Ссылки:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="" class="phone-on-desc" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CallBackModal"><span>Заказать обратный звонок</span></a>

<a class="palisad_infoblock-innerpages-callbutton" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CallBackModal">ИЛИ ЗАКАЖИТЕ БЕСПЛАТНЫЙ ЗВОНОК</a>




<div class="modal fade" id="CallBackModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CallBackModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal_width">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Закажите обратный звонок</b></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?=do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="195" title="Заказ звонка"]')?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу пример или код и укажите версию bootstrap

Comment: а какая разница, какая версия?! Проблема скорее на самой странице

Comment: Например какая?

Comment: зачем у `div` нужно `tabindex`? Его можно применять, только к `<a>, <area>, <button>, <input>, <object>, <select>, <textarea>`, для переключения по `TAB`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так, у меня работает:

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
$('body').css('position','fixed');
```

Но в последних версиях `bootstrap` данная проблема исправлена.